# How to refer to the join column field (@OneToMany case) in a hibernate sql (HQL) query?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a class `Customer` which has the following getter:

```
   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID") // join column is in table for Order
   public Set<Order> getOrders() {return orders;}
```

So the column `CUST_ID` is the `Order` class.

How can I refer to this column in HQL?

E.g.

```
entityManager.createQuery("FROM Order o WHERE o.CUST_ID = 1")
```

Do I need some kind of a getter or a special annotation in the Order class?

At the moment Hibernate can not recognise the column (`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property`). With usual SQL I see the column in the table correctly.

Comment: I prefer to mapper OneToMany in different way: 

In Customer: 
`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "order")`

In Order: 
`@JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_order_customer"))
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

And try to use the solution proposed by @ Maciej Kowalski.

Comment: You aren't using SQL, as any doc would tell you. The query language operates around OBJECTS. So join to the related object and select the "id" of that. And JPQL starts with "SELECT " FWIW

Answer (score 3):

You should move the `@JoinColumn` to Order entity and alter the `@OneToMany`:

**Customer**:

```
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer")
   public Set<Order> getOrders() {return orders;}
```

**Order**:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID")
public Customer getCustomer();
```

**The query**:

```
entityManager.createQuery("FROM Order  o INNER JOIN o.customer c WHERE c.custId = 1")
```

In general `@JoinColumn` is meant for `@ManyToOne`. `@JoinTable` is used along with `@OneToMany` but this is not necessary in your case.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but somehow I am not able to make it work.
The solution you propose with the annotated field does not work for me, because I have annotations for getters and I can not mix both.
That is why I have created a getter and setter and tried to annotate the getter like you proposed, however the column now only contains null values.

Comment: ManyToOne can be on the getter of course. I have updated the post

Comment: Thanks, I had it exactly like you proposed. I have also tried the ForeignKey annotation but still no success. The column only contains null values. Just for completeness, my CUST_ID definition is like that:
     private String custId; 
    @Id
    @Column(name="CUST_ID")
    public String getCustId() {
        return custId;
    }

Comment: I have altered the query. Do you get any actual errors?

Comment: No, no errors. It works. But the CUST_ID column does not contain values.

Comment: I have managed to get a working version by including the @JoinColumn-Annotation on both sides (Customer and Order) and adding OneToMany on one side and ManyToOne on the other side. I could then write a query with an inner join which worked. Is such a solution OK or am I doing something completely wrong?

Comment: That JoinColumn on OneToMany is not necessary.